# Download a dynamic SWF written in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, download, flash

I'm trying to download SWF files from a site the traditional way, but a few of the SWF files have been created dynamically through what I believe to be ASP.net 2.0.

Every attempt to D/Load results in the correct dimensions, height and width, but it just gives me empty white space.

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Why do you think that they've been created with ASP, other than they just display white?

Comment: The CMS was designed through ASP.  It allows admins to load images which then get turned into a SWF on the front-end.  I have access to that back-end, and the front-end SWF files, but not the code that translates these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do the SWF files do? Perhaps you have managed to download the SWF fine, but it has an internal check for some requirement? Are there 'flashvars' being passed into it or pulled from a QueryString perhaps?

If you view the site that has the SWF files working with something like Fiddler or HttpFox it might provide some insights?

Comment: Hey Neil!  I used HttpFox per your suggestion.  There aren't any queries being run for those particular SWFs.  The SWF files right now display images uploaded by an admin through a custom ASP.net CMS.  I have access to only the CMS admin, but none of the actual coding :(  --thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: my guess is the swf files are accepting flash vars, probably a comma sep list of image paths, which then get loaded and displayed.

Comment: Yea, I think so, too.  In that case, I'm plum out of luck?